# $(window).width() returns different width than indicated by Chrome DevTools

Tags: jquery, width

When `$(window).width() == 768`, an `alert()` is executed. But in `Chrome DevTools` this actually happens when width is 786px. Why and how to make my JS fire at 768px not 786?

Comment: The reason why is because width() excludes scrollbars. Do you have a scrollbar on when that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply:

```
window.innerWidth
```

or for backwards-compatibility with older browers

```
window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth
```

Comment: `document.body.clientWidth` worked for me, but how do you decide which one to use?

Comment: I guess we never know